# Swing: hidden JPanel added with dimensions equal to 0 is not recomputed when turned to visible

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, repaint

I have this program where there are two panels, one with 2 toggle buttons to the left and one that shows a label to the right.
When selected, every button add its panel in the right area (and sets invisible the other).
When deselected they remove it.
In the last case I want the other panel (if added to the container) to turn visible.
The code basically works, but if the 2nd button was deselected at the start panel 1 did not appears.
I found that panel 1 has its dimensions set to 0 and if I manually set this dimensions, the panel appears. Unfortunately by doing so the Layout Manager stops to handle the panel dimensions (when I resize the window or the JSplitPanel, this is BAD!!).

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setSize(800, 800);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            final JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            final JToggleButton btn1 = new JToggleButton("Button 1");
            final JToggleButton btn2 = new JToggleButton("Button 2");

            buttonsPanel.add(btn1);
            buttonsPanel.add(btn2);

            final JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            final JPanel pan1;
            final JPanel pan2;
            pan1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            pan2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

            pan1.add(new JLabel("panel 1"));
            pan2.add(new JLabel("panel 2"));

            pan1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            pan2.setBackground(Color.RED);

            btn1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e) {
                    final int state = e.getStateChange();
                    for (final Component component : containerPanel.getComponents()) {
                        component.setVisible(false);
                    }

                    if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                        containerPanel.add(pan1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        pan1.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        containerPanel.remove(pan1);
                        for (final Component component : containerPanel.getComponents()) {
                            component.setVisible(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    containerPanel.invalidate();
                    containerPanel.repaint();
                }
            });

            btn2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e) {
                    final int state = e.getStateChange();
                    for (final Component component : containerPanel.getComponents()) {
                        component.setVisible(false);
                    }

                    if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                        pan2.setVisible(true);
                        containerPanel.add(pan2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    }
                    else {
                        containerPanel.remove(pan2);
                        for (final Component component : containerPanel.getComponents()) {
                            component.setVisible(true);
                            // component.setSize(containerPanel.getSize());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    containerPanel.revalidate();
                    containerPanel.repaint();
                }
            });

            btn1.setSelected(true);
            btn2.setSelected(true);

            final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                                                        true,
                                                        buttonsPanel,
                                                        containerPanel);
            splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
            frame.add(splitPane);
            frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    });

}
```

How can I solve this issue without manually set the other panel dimensions?
I know that a CardLayout is a solution to this type of requirements, but unfortunately it's not applicable to my problem.

Thanks

**edit:**
As requested in comments here is a simple sequence of actions for explain the problem:

What I expect:

1. Start the application -> both buttons are selected, both panels are added to the right container, only panel 2 is visible (because Button 2 is the last to be selected by code).
2. Deselect Button 2 -> panel 2 is removed from the right container, panel 1 is switched to visible and appears in the right container.

What really happens:

1. The same as expected
2. panel 1 is not shown because its dimensions are both 0, invalidate and repaint didn't works

Comment: *"I know that a CardLayout is a solution to this type of requirements, but unfortunately it's not applicable to my problem."*  Why not?

Comment: Because to do so I need to do a large refactoring on code that isn't under my control. If there is a solution that I can keep under my control it will be my favourite.

Comment: Seems odd you are using two toggle buttons to switch between two panels. Toggle buttons have two states and should have two decision for, one for each state. So why do you need _two_ toggle buttons to switch between the panels? Just use regular buttons with action listeners, or just one toggle button.

Comment: @peeskillet one toggle button can't handle the case when both panels are plugged but only one is visible and all transactions that I need to handle. This example is a simplified version of much complex application.

Comment: Can you edit your post with a simple numbered sequence of events 1. For what you expect to happen, and 2. for what is actually happening. Don't really understand your post

Comment: @peeskillet done the edit, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

> "both panels are added to the right container, only panel 2 is visible"

That is incorrect. You are using `BorderLayout`. The catch is that each position can only have *one* component. The first one gets kicked out (no longer exists in the container) and only the last one added remains, and you are trying to add both to the `CENTER`

So your assumption that by removing the the second panel, the first will automatically appear when you call setVisible, is incorrect. The component actually needs to be added again.

Based off this new information, try and debug your problem. Also use `revalidate()` instead of `invalidate()`

> "panel 1 is not shown because its dimensions are both 0"

Has nothing to do with that. `BorderLayout` doesn't care about the size. It will stretch the panel to fit.

---

Aside: this is the perfect situation for CardLayout. Not really sure why you can't use it, but maybe you should dig deeper into possibilities of implementing it

---

**UPDATE**

I think this may be what you're looking for. It's just a matter of toggling the other button's state.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(800, 800);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                final JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
                final JToggleButton btn1 = new JToggleButton("Button 1");
                final JToggleButton btn2 = new JToggleButton("Button 2");

                buttonsPanel.add(btn1);
                buttonsPanel.add(btn2);

                final JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                final JPanel pan1;
                final JPanel pan2;
                pan1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                pan2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

                pan1.add(new JLabel("panel 1"));
                pan2.add(new JLabel("panel 2"));

                pan1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                pan2.setBackground(Color.RED);

                btn1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e) {
                        final int state = e.getStateChange();

                        if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                            containerPanel.add(pan1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            containerPanel.remove(pan2);
                            btn2.getModel().setSelected(false);
                        } else {
                            containerPanel.add(pan2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            containerPanel.remove(pan1);
                            btn2.getModel().setSelected(true);
                        }
                        containerPanel.revalidate();
                        containerPanel.repaint();
                    }
                });

                btn2.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void itemStateChanged(final ItemEvent e) {
                        final int state = e.getStateChange();
                        if (state == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                            containerPanel.add(pan2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            containerPanel.remove(pan1);
                            btn1.getModel().setSelected(false);
                        } else {
                            containerPanel.add(pan1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            containerPanel.remove(pan2);
                            btn1.getModel().setSelected(true);
                        }

                        containerPanel.revalidate();
                        containerPanel.repaint();
                    }
                });

                btn1.setSelected(true);
                btn2.setSelected(true);

                final JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                        true,
                        buttonsPanel,
                        containerPanel);
                splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
                frame.add(splitPane);
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Some parts of this answer are incorrect:
1. the first panel was not kicked out, the code is able to find it in the container and call .setVisible(true) without a NullPointerException;
2. if .setSize() is called on the first panel it really appears (you can try the code).

Anyway, as you said, removing and add again the panel works and it  appears with its dimensions handled by the LayoutManager.
I will try with revalidate() too.

Comment: Yeah I guess you're right. Never had to worry about it before

Comment: revalidate() don't works. Thanks anyway, I think that as you say the problem is that the FlowLayout don't handle more than one component for one location (even if other components aren't kicked out from the container) and it's not able to recompute other components dimensions once the "first" is removed. I don't know if use the remove()/add() trick or refactor and use CardLayout (sad me).

Comment: I Say CardLayout. What you are doing seems odd. For the simple reason that each toggle button has two states. So you have four states you need to account for. But you only have two views. So trying to make four states perform two actions seems to over complicate it

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. Test it out. I think that may be what you're looking for. Let me know

Comment: " the first panel was not kicked out, the code is able to find it in the container and call .setVisible(true) without a NullPointerException" This is because your `run()` method has a valid reference to the JPanel which can be used by your event callback methods. This has nothing to do with the behavior of the `BorderLayout`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I actually tested it with `mainPanel.getComponents().length` after adding both panels and setting the frame visible, and it still said 2 :-) That's why I said the OP was right. Maybe you thouhgt we were talking about the view, but we talking about the actual container itself.

Comment: @peeskillet I can see other possibilities for the two components...What is `mainPanel`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice just some arbitrary name. Just create three panel. One `mainPanel` with borderlayout. Add the two panels to it (CENTER). Add to a frame, show the frame. spring out the components lendth of the the mainPanel you will get 2. That was what the OP was talking about, the container still having the panels even though one just gets kicked out the _view_

Comment: @peeskillet I would also suggest checking the reference id against those of the known JPanels.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice so are you arguing that the other panel is kicked out the container. Just wondering, because you seem to be sure. I will test in a bit

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yup, both panels are still in the mainpanel

Comment: @peeskillet are you shure your code has not a loop? select/deselect a button call the opposite method to the other button and so on. Anyway you must not to focus on my code where I use only 2 panel, as I said my code is a sample of more complex application (a backend to plug panels to a frame) and I need it to simulate the transitions,the empy container status and other things.